# Understanding use of における

Tags: grammar

> 明治【めいじ】時代【じだい】**における**学校【がっこう】教育【きょういく】について

Please help understand the use of ～における.  Is it a form of `において`?

Why wouldn't it be a past form then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`における` can be thought of as a prefix version of `において`. While you can say for example `△においては`, this usually means something like "about △", `における` can be used when you want to focus on a particular aspect of your subject matter. In this case your subject matter is the Meiji era, and you are focusing on its school education. You can also translate `における` as "pertaining to". I would translate your phrase, depending on the continuation, as

> About the school education of/during the Meiji era...

Comment: So,における is a separate grammatical construct by itself;and bears no relationship to において.

Comment: @IUnknown They have a historical relationship (they both come from 置く).